# Deploying a CXF web service in Spring Framework

Tags: java, web-services, spring, wsdl, cxf

After running through the CXF samples I had a simple web service up and running fine. However I would like to integrate it with a Spring web application inside a servlet container. After updating the servlet.xml config file:

```
<jaxws:endpoint id="HelloWorldService"
implementor="path.to.webservice.HelloWorldImpl"
endpointName="e:HelloEndpoint"
serviceName="s:HelloService"
address="/HelloService"
xmlns:e="http://service.jaxws.cxf.apache.org/endpoint"
xmlns:s="http://service.jaxws.cxf.apache.org/service"/>
```

and web.xml:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>CXFServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>CXFServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/services/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

I was able to deploy it in the servlet but the WSDL of the Spring service is horribly wrong even though the Java interface and implementing files are identical. See Eclipse WSDL outlines below:

[alt text http://img171.imageshack.us/i/correcty.jpg/](http://img171.imageshack.us/i/correcty.jpg/)[alt text http://img190.imageshack.us/i/wrongia.jpg/](http://img190.imageshack.us/i/wrongia.jpg/)

Why would such different WSDL be generated from identical .java files and how can I get it working in the servlet? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't see the wsdl outlines for commenting, and as such different Service Engines generate different WSDL's

Answer (score 0):

The WSDL and schema depend on the choice of front end and data binding in CXF.  If your other environment is not JAX-WS+JAXB, the same version, you will get very different results. Even if it is merely a non-CXF version of those, you can expect cosmetically different results.